# Set intersection not working

Tags: c++, stl, set

I'm trying to make the intersection of two sets using the following code and if the result is different than the empty set i want to insert the first of my sets into a set of sets.

```
    std::set<int> set1,set2;
    std::set<set<int> > result;
    std::set<int> intersection;
             set_intersection(set1.begin(),set1.end(),set2.begin(),set2.end(),std::back_inserter(intersection));
                if(!intersection.empty()) result.insert(set1);
```

However i get the following error: 'class std::set' has no member named 'push_back'. What is the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read the [documentation of `std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)

Comment: I did. Am i missing something? Insert is a member of set, and i am not using push_back anywhere. Or am i not using insert the right way? Does it have something to do with iterators?

Comment: @Andy: [`back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) creates a [`back_insert_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator) which calls `push_back`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::back_inserter` uses `std::back_inserter_iterator`, which calls `push_back()` on the container.

Use `std::inserter` when the output is an `std::set`.

```
 std::set<int> set1,set2;
 std::set<int> intersection;
 std::set_intersection(set1.begin(),set1.end(),set2.begin(),set2.end(),
                       std::inserter(intersection, intersection.begin()));
```